# has_many and has_one, any advantages/disadvantages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

This is just a general question. Lets assume that I have the following situation: I have a Patient (many) and a Doctor (few) model. I want each patient to be related to one doctor. I can do it now two ways, either doctor has_many patients or the patient has_one doctor. Does using the one or another has any dis-/advantages or is it completely irrelevant which one I use?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like you want to have a many to many relationship, otherwise you won't have any history between doctor and patient if the patient changes doctors.
So you make a 3rd table, add a foreign key for both Patient and Doctor.